# How to save both a value and a text using collection_select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the *user* table there is a place for 'country_id' and country name represented by 'country' field (redundancy is a conscious decision)

**My problem is:**
'country' field is empty. I must have use the collection_select helper in the wrong way? How to fix it?

**here is my form:**

```
<%= form_for :user, url: users_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all, :id, :country_name ) %>
...
```

**Here is my create action:**

```
    def create
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            @user.save
            redirect_to @user
        end
    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:country_id, :country ... )
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not how web browsers work. Only the value attribute of the  tag and the name attribute of the parent select is sent by the browser. This is deserialized by Rack into a hash.

While you could join the id and name together as the value its not needed in the first place. That "redundancy" is really just duplication which is a bigger problem. If the name of a country is changed then you will get user records which contain the wrong data. You would have to setup an expensive update callback or trigger to avoid that.

If having a country is important you need to enforce it by having constraints in the database and validations in your application.

You want to ensure that the `users.country_id` column is not nullable and has a foreign key constraint to enforce referential integrity.

On the application side the `belongs_to` association macro in Rails 5 defaults to `optional: false` so you don't need to set anything up.

Comment: at this moment you've convinced me to get rid of this redundancy. let me sleep with the idea and I will back. If you can explain/extend the 'deserialized by Rack into a hash' I would appreciate that. ID and the name together is an interesting idea but I don't want to present IDs to user. I wonder how often counties changes names... I think not so often, but you right. I don't want to remember about it. The redundancy was to avoid one join - but maybe I do too much to reduce database usage. I have constraints of course ... has_many and belongs to are in place. Anyway good tip. Thank you

Comment: The browser serializes the form inputs into a string of key/value pairs. Rack (the underlying Ruby CGI) parses this and builds the params hash out of it. You can use the network tab in the web inspector to see what the raw request body looks like.

Comment: For example the above comment is `comment=The+browser+serializes+the+form+inputs+into+a+string+of+key%2Fvalue+pairs.+Rack+(the+underlying+Ruby+CGI)+parses+this+and+builds+the+params+hash+out+of+it.+You+can+use+the+network+tab+in+the+web+inspector+to+see+what+the+raw+request+body+looks+like.&fkey=08ff7415b590f56aeb6ddf71549cff57`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use 'options_from_collection_for_select' instead

This is more often than used inside a #select_tag like this example:

```
select_tag 'person', options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name')
```

Comment: You can go through this [Link](http://andrewradev.com/2011/05/25/grouped-select-helper-methods-in-rails/) You can find something useful..